# how to solve fbs error 'Can not find path ./libshiboken2.abi3.5.13.dylib'?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside2, python-standalone, fbs

I have been able to freeze a Python/PySide2 script with fbs on macOS, and the app seems to work.
However, I got some errors from the freeze process stating:

> Can not find path ./libshiboken2.abi3.5.13.dylib.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **--runtime-tmpdir** because while running the generated exe file it needs this file **libshiboken2.abi3.5.13.dylib** and unable hook that file.

Solution: use **--add-data** & **--runtime-tmpdir** to pyinstaller command line.

**pyinstaller -F --add-data "path/libshiboken2.abi3.5.13.dylib":"**PATH**"
**--runtime-tmpdir temp_dir_name your_program.py**

here **PATH**  = the directory name of that file looking for.**-F** = one file